# Prop not available in Vue.js component method even though it's present in this object

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am passing a prop to my component like this:

```
<friend-create-form v-bind:group-id="group_id"></friend-create-form>
```

In the component I have this:

```
<script>
    import Multiselect from 'vue-multiselect';
    const axios = require('axios');

    // register globally
    Vue.component('multiselect', Multiselect);

    export default {
        components: { Multiselect },
        props: ['groupId'],
        data () {
            return {
                group: {},
                friend: {},
                options: [],
                errors: []
            }
        },
        methods: {
            addTag(newTag) {
                const tag = {
                    name: newTag,
                    code: newTag.substring(0, 2) + Math.floor((Math.random() * 10000000))
                };
                this.options.push(tag);
                this.friend.tags.push(tag);
            },
            fetchGroup() {

                console.log(this.groupId);

            }
        },
        mounted : function(){

            this.fetchGroup();

        }
    }
</script>
```

When I inspect the component in vue dev tools, I see the prop is there:

[image: vue dev tools]

However, the `console.log` in the mounted method says `groupId` is `false`. I am stuck here. When I `console.log(this)` in the same place it looks like the scope isn't the issue, `this` seems to be the whole vue instance so it should contain the props, no?

I tried a solution found in another SO answer, but it gave a syntax error:

```
${this.groupid}
```

Comment: Is the `groupId` somehow updated asynchronously by the parent, i.e. after the `mounted()` lifecycle hook has fired?

Comment: @Terry No, there's nothing in the parent currently except initially setting the group_id value when mounted.

Comment: Just to be 100% sure please change the ES5 `mounted` hook to ES6 `mounted() {}` and try again please.

Comment: @Stephan-v Just tried it, no effect.

Comment: Maybe there's a misunderstanding regarding camel case and kebab case here? I don't think there should be but perhaps I'm missing something?

Comment: Show us where group_id is created in the parent mount. My guess is that it is asynchronously created.